# Displaying more charts ( from list ) in chart panel

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

If you follow my reproducible example you get list of 35 charts then I want to see them in groups of 4. I used mfrow before but now when I run a commands to display chart whole screen is overwritten by single chart . Can you help ?

```
library(tidyverse)
x<-split(diamonds, with(diamonds, interaction(cut,color)), drop = TRUE)

graphs<-list()
for (i in 1:length(x))
  local({
    i<-i
    chart<-print(ggplot(x[[i]],aes(x=clarity,fill=clarity))+
                   geom_bar())

    graphs[[i]]<<-chart
    i=i+1
    print(i)
  })

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
graphs[[1]]
graphs[[2]]
graphs[[3]]
graphs[[4]]
```

Comment: see the `grid` package, `gridExtra` or `cowplot`

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in one go with ggplot facets

```
ggplot(diamonds,aes(x=clarity,fill=clarity)) + geom_bar() +
    facet_grid(cut~color,scales = "free_y") +
        theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank())
```

Note that i used `scales = "free_y"` and removed the x-labels with `theme()` because these became very crowded.

Comment: did you meant `scales = "free_y"`?

Comment: Yes, it should have been "free_y", which I corrected. Thanks.